# Is "switch to other business" idiomatic?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

> People often perform a double-click on a Zoom link and switch to other business.

In the above sentence, I intend to say people click a Zoom meeting link, and although their computers are attending a meeting, they often switch to work on other things, i.e., not paying attention to this meeting.

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/business?q=business) has

> [uncountable] important matters that need to be dealt with or discussed:
>
> He has some unfinished business to deal with.

as well as "get down to business", "go about your business".

Does "switch to other business" idiomatically mean "switch to work on other things"? If not, is there any phrase meaning "not pay attention to something and work on something else"?

Comment: It's okay, but I'd say other windows or other activities on their desktop.

Comment: 1) The meaning didn't present itself to me immediately until you'd explained your intent. The problem might not be only "business," but that "switch to" could be clearer. Perhaps "... and then turn their attention to other activities" or similar. 2) It shouldn't bug me, but I can't ignore it—you don't have to *double*-click a link!!

Comment: @AndyBonner It's good that you catch the "double-click". When can business mean important matters, work, or things? Do I have to use the phrases in the dictionary?

Comment: "Business" certainly can mean "what you're focusing on"; I think the problem was that there are so few words in the sentence that using more specific words is better. "Business" can also mean "the industry of corporate careers," and people often use Zoom for "business" purposes, so there's a potential for confusion.

Comment: 'But' brings out the contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think “switch to other business” is the right thing to say, as that phrase has more meaning than just switching to another activity.

I would probably just say something like:

> People often click on a Zoom link and then do other things in the background.

To me this is very idiomatic.

“In the background” here implies that the fact they are not paying attention to the meeting goes mostly unnoticed.

Comment: I don't mean they have to continue using the computer. They can switch to playing ping-pong or go to eat while the computer is there attending the meeting.

Comment: I see, I've changed my answer.